# showing error for creating table with foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE location (
  uid int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state_uid` int not null,
  FOREIGN KEY location(state_uid)
  REFERENCES state(uid)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  `city_uid` int not null,
  FOREIGN KEY location(city_uid)
  REFERENCES city(uid)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  `area_uid` int not null,
  FOREIGN KEY location(area_uid)
  REFERENCES area(uid)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: what error you getting

Comment: duplicate key name location

Comment: use this   CONSTRAINT description FOREIGN KEY  (nameofcolumn) REFERENCES RefferanceTable(primaryKey Name)

Comment: k i will try in my DataBase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE location  (
  uid int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  state_uid int not null, 
  city_uid int not null,
  area_uid int not null,

  CONSTRAINT fk_state FOREIGN KEY (state_uid)  REFERENCES state(uid)  ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_city  FOREIGN KEY (city_uid)  REFERENCES city(uid)  ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_area FOREIGN KEY (area_uid)  REFERENCES area(uid)   
);
```

Try this query

make sure parent tables exists

Comment: my pleasure pavan

Answer (score 0):

Your version is almost just fine.  The problem is the `location` in the foreign key reference.

You have no issue with the cascading stuff or the ordering of the columns.  So, this works:

```
CREATE TABLE location (
  uid int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state_uid` int not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (state_uid) REFERENCES state(uid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  `city_uid` int not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (city_uid) REFERENCES city(uid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  `area_uid` int not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (area_uid) REFERENCES area(uid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cccc9f) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note that it is often traditional to put explicit `foreign key` (and other constraints) after the column definitions, there is no rule or standard for this.  In fact, most databases support in-line foreign key definitions.  MySQL does not, however.